Differentiation between two iteratively computed functions
Imagine I have two variables that are updated iteratively: $y_t = f(x_{t})$ and $x_{t+1} = g(y_{t})$, so they inherently have some "time dependency". Now for $s<t$, by the standard differentiation rule, we have $dx_s/dy_t=(dy_t/dx_s)^{-1}$, but I find this to be counter-intuitive -- $x_s$ happened in the past of $y_t$, why would the change of $y_t$ has an effect on $x_s$?
On the other hand, in a system like this, if I say I approximate $dx_s/dy_t$ by $0$, is there a name for such approximation?

There's nothing inherent in the notation $\frac{dy}{dx}$ that requires that the relation between $y$ and $x$ is being caused in one direction or the other, it just tells you how changes in $y$ and $x$ relate to each other.
As a much simpler example, consider a car driving on a straight road. Its location at time $t$ and time $t'$ are directly related, so you can easily express $x = x(t)$ and $x' = x(t')$ in terms of each other and even calculate the derivative $\frac{dx'}{dx}$, but it doesn't mean that the car's current position caused it to have a particular position 5 minutes ago.
If you need to be able to express such a derivative in terms of causal relationships, you could think of it as something like "If I had observed a different measurement for the system now, what kind of change in the system previously would have had to happen to cause that?"
